# Можно ли на Linux сделать exe файл для Windows? Если можно, то как?

Tags: python, windows, exe, linux

Можно ли на Linux сделать exe файл для Windows? Если можно, то как?

Comment: Как минимум можно попробовать запустить под wine компилятор, но это изврат. Если речь о том что-бы упаковать python программу в exe то это наверняка можно сделать как-то проще.

Но программу в любом случае придётся тестировать под виндой.

Comment: Боюсь, даже по wine будут проблемы - программам типа py2exe или PyInstaller необходимо отслеживать зависимости от виндовых DLL, что под wine не всегда получится. Вроде как разработчики PyInstaller работают над отрывом от зависимостей, но не уверен, что это полностью удалось, надо смотреть. Так что, IMHO - vmplayer с нужным образом + [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)...

Comment: >vmplayer

VirtualBox

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но не без гемороя. И не только для Windows, но и для OSx или ARM-ахитектур. У меня знакомый хотел так сделать, но потом отказался от этой идеи - хлопотно. Это называется cross compiling. 
Вот, покурите мануалы:

- [Cross
     compiling](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling)
- [Cross compiling for Win32 under
     Linux](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling_for_Win32_under_Linux)
- [Cross Compiling Under Linux](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cross-Compiling_Under_Linux)
- [Compile for Windows on Linux](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/)